# Database design help required

Tags: database-design, normalization

I need help in building simple database structure. Kind of stuck.

Here's what I'm trying.

Class means Department+Semester. Eg, Electronics Engineering SemI, Electrical Engg Sem II.. etc..

Student is in class;
Class has a defined group of subjects;
Group consists of multiple subjects.

Class and Subjects, 2 entities depend on same SubjectGroup entity. So isn't this a ternary relationship ?

I've made this image to make picture clear.
[ P = Primary key; F = Foreign Key; Arrows do not mean anything of One-to-many/many to many etc.. they are just showing what referenced where]

[image]

I am stuck because I can not refer to GroupId two times.

How should I modify this structure ?

-
Thanks

Comment: If this is homework, tag it as homework please.

Comment: what back end?  or just on paper for now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Entities

- Student.
- Class.
- Subject.

### Relationships

- Student to Class.  One to Many.  One class relates to many students.
- Subject to Class.  One to Many.  One class relates to many subjects.

### Tables

#### Student

Columns:

- studentId - primary key of the student table.
- stuff about sutdent (some number of columns).
- classId - foreign key into the class table.

#### Subject

Columns:

- subjectId - primary key of the subject table.
- stuff about subject (some number of columns).
- classId - foreign key into the class table.

#### Class

- classId - primary key of the class table.
- stuff about a class.  nothing about student.  nothing about subject.  no foreign key to student.  no foreign key to subject.

### Queries

#### Students in a class

```
select
    s.studentName
from
    class c
    inner join student s on s.classId = c.classId
where
    c.classId = 'desired class id'
```

#### Subjects Student is Studying

```
select
    sub.subjectName
from
    student stu
    inner join subject sub on sub.classId = stu.classId
where
    stu.studentId = 'desired student id'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
well, relations are little different.
One student to one class only but one class to many students.
One class to many subjects and One subject to only one class.

student to class doesn't seem problematic. I'm not getting the other one.
1 student has 1 class and 1 class has many subjects.
'1 class' is needed to be referred in 2 relations.

It will help me understand quickly if one can give at least pseudo-sql..
I can't understand theoretically much. Code is fine.

Comment: @deb and Omie: please don't use the word Relation when you really mean Relationship. They are completely different concepts. In the context of relational database design they ought not to be confused!

Comment: I see you've referred same primary key column in 2 tables. If that had worked for me before, I wouldn't have asked this question. For some reason.. MySql keep throwing Errno-150 on adding Foreign Key constraint. I'll look into it and will post new question if that happens again. So far, I'm going with you suggestion. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to introduce a classSubject table.
Is this an accurate example of rows?

```
student
beth
john
mark

class
beths_and_johns_class bethssubject, johnssubject
marks_class markssubject

subject
bethssubject
johnssubject
markssubject
```